# How to access to collection through scoped association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :projects, through: :assignments
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :users, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :project
    scope :current_assignments, where(...)
end
```

I want to get all projects currently assigned to the current user. Something like:

```
current_user.current_assigned_projects
```

But right now, I have to do:

```
current_user.assignments.current_assignments.map{ |a| a.project }.uniq
```

or

```
Project.includes(:users, :assignments).where('assignments.status' => 1, 'users.id' => current_user.id)
```

Is there any beautiful way to do this?

Comment: Seems to me that `current_user.projects` should work.

Comment: It gives me all projects. I want all projects obtained by applying the scope :current_assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :assignments
   has_many :projects, through: :assignments
   has_many :current_projects, conditions: 'assignments.status = 1', through: :assignments
end
```

should work. Or at least I hope so ;)